# Load from External txt file

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs5.5

Hi i wanted to load a external .txt file to a dynamic text field in Flash CS5.5 using Actionscript 2 but it loads only 609 lines (13070 Characters) !!! Well the list is really big and has about 2500 + lines... I need to load them all ....
I used these codes:

```
myData = new LoadVars();
myData.onLoad = function() {
textInstance.text = this.myVariable;
};
myData.load("Shopids.txt");
```

If you know any alternate way of loading lots of texts to a dynamic text field pls help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Aww I found the answer myself :D

My text file had "**&**" symbol.....

After i removed it all the contents were loaded :)

I hope this will be useful for some !